# How to disable compression handling in Apache HttpAsyncClient

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient

When creating a normal CloseableHttpClient I can disable compression (and redirections) by doing

```
httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .disableRedirectHandling()
            .disableContentCompression()
            .build();
```

This way I receive gzip data unaltered.
Now I'm trying the same with CloseableHttpAsyncClient, but the relevant methods are missing from HttpAsyncClients.custom():

```
asyncHttpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
    .disableContentCompression() // COMPILE ERROR
    .build();
```

I'm just at the start of evaluating the feasability or rewriting my code to the async API so I might be missing something. How is the async client going to handle compressed content? Can its behavior be customized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HttpAsyncClient 4.x currently does not support automatic content decompression.